# Host is unresolved: api. facebook.com:443

Tags: android

I am getting "Host is unresolved: api. facebook.com:443" error in logcat
while I try to authorize Facebook from my android app.
Any idea why it would be happening?

Log cat:

```
01-10 15:28:55.891: E/Facebook(1084): Host is unresolved: api.facebook.com:443
01-10 15:28:55.918: W/System.err(1084): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: api.facebook.com:443
01-10 15:28:55.938: W/System.err(1084):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1038)
01-10 15:28:55.938: W/System.err(1084):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
01-10 15:28:55.938: W/System.err(1084):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
01-10 15:28:56.047: W/System.err(1084):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
01-10 15:28:56.047: W/System.err(1084):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
01-10 15:28:56.047: W/System.err(1084):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:396)
01-10 15:28:56.047: W/System.err(1084):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:147)
01-10 15:28:56.088: W/System.err(1084):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:178)
01-10 15:28:56.088: W/System.err(1084):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
01-10 15:28:56.088: W/System.err(1084):     at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:253)
```

Comment: 01-10 15:28:55.891: E/Facebook(1084): Host is unresolved: api.facebook.com:443
01-10 15:28:55.918: W/System.err(1084): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: api.facebook.com:443
01-10 15:28:55.938: W/System.err(1084):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1038)

Comment: How do you connect to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`<uses-permission>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) in your `AndroidManifest.xml` with [`android.permission.INTERNET`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET).

Comment: Are you sure it's directly under `<manifest>`, and not somewhere else? Also, is the device you are testing on connected to the Internet? Can you browse Facebook in the browser?